Difference in division results of big integers between Rust and Go
I've encountered an interesting issue while working with large integers in Rust and Go. Specifically, the results of division operations differ between the two languages when dealing with negative dividends. Here is the code for both languages:
Rust
use num_bigint::BigInt;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    let n = BigInt::from_str("-4068122527548036313624952687320999183219209139149389824425650628448701979991259532638609685663741905551578447595775644964695361846038949186131821248175179900695219937607954907860922507949244416").unwrap();
    let d = BigInt::from_str(
        "115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337",
    )
    .unwrap();
    let res = &n / &d;
    println!("res:{}", result);
}

Go
package main

import "math/big"

func main() {
    var n, d, res big.Int
    n.SetString("-4068122527548036313624952687320999183219209139149389824425650628448701979991259532638609685663741905551578447595775644964695361846038949186131821248175179900695219937607954907860922507949244416", 10)
    d.SetString("115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337", 10)
    res.Div(&n, &d)
    println("res:", res.String())
}

Output
Rust: -35132991850681684771865987637349505035135798334672277824131793024179346079627919418184483600280933255791109974931548
Go: -35132991850681684771865987637349505035135798334672277824131793024179346079627919418184483600280933255791109974931549
As you can see, Rust rounds the result towards zero, while Go rounds towards negative infinity. Can anyone explain why this difference exists and whether there is a way to align the behavior of these two languages in such division operations?

FWIW Python 3 calculates …49

JS calculates …48

According to https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Div, Int.Div and Int.DivMod use Euclidean division (unlike the Go behavior for basic numeric types), whereas Int.QuoRem truncates towards zero (like basic types, -4 / 3 == -1)

"Can anyone explain why this difference exists" because there are at least five different ways to implement integer division in computers and implementors have to pick one, on various grounds (convenience, coherence, performance, ...). In this case, rust-bigint follows "normal" rust integers and uses a truncating division by default with euclidean as an opt-in, while go-bigint breaks away from the base language and defaults to euclidean.

I got …48 in Go by using Quo instead of Div.

num_bigint appears to be using a different rounding strategy per default:
use num_bigint::BigInt;
use num_integer::Integer;
use num_traits::ops::euclid::Euclid;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    let n = BigInt::from_str("-4068122527548036313624952687320999183219209139149389824425650628448701979991259532638609685663741905551578447595775644964695361846038949186131821248175179900695219937607954907860922507949244416").unwrap();
    let d = BigInt::from_str(
        "115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337",
    )
    .unwrap();
    let rust = BigInt::from_str("-35132991850681684771865987637349505035135798334672277824131793024179346079627919418184483600280933255791109974931548").unwrap();
    let go = BigInt::from_str("-35132991850681684771865987637349505035135798334672277824131793024179346079627919418184483600280933255791109974931549").unwrap();
    let res = &n / &d;
    assert_eq!(res, rust);
    let res = n.div_floor(&d);
    assert_eq!(res, go);
    let res = n.div_euclid(&d);
    assert_eq!(res, go);
}

